# Weekday by timezone with mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone

I don't seem to find something that I think it's pretty standard. So, let's say we have the following query:

```
select * from mytable  where  WEEKDAY(datetime_field)=4;
```

This will return all the records that happened on Friday according to my pre-configured timezone.  What I would like to know is how do I have the day given another timezone. I would need something like.

```
select * from mytable  where  WEEKDAY(datetime_field, timezone)=4;
```

However I don't find a function like `WEEKDAY(datetime_field, timezone)`. Or at least I didn't find it in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday).

Is there a way to perform such query.

Note: *This would apply not only for weekday, also for day of the month or of the year, which depending on the timezone is going to happen at different* times.

Comment: Weekday seems to be entirely irrelevant here. You simply want to know how to return a datetime_field relative to another timezone.

Comment: I want to know the day so I can query that information. It's not the same all information from Friday in EST (Eastern Time Zone) that CET (Central European Time) for example. Because Friday didn't start or end at the same time.

Comment: Yes. But once you add or subtract the requisite number of hours from your datetime, you can just use the normal date functions.

Comment: I'm looking for an fast solution. I could probably write a function to do it. But I want to avoid reinventing the wheel if there's some optimal functionality that already tackles this problem. (I'm also far from being a mysql expert, so I would do it pretty unoptimally).

Comment: We're not in the business of fast solutions. That's why we're free. In all other respects, CONVERT_TZ()  appears to satisfy your needs.

Comment: By fast I meant optimal. It's not about being free, it's about writing good software =). It seems `CONVERT_TZ` is what I'm looking for. I'm gonna give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Strawberry I found a solution based on the `CONVERT_TZ` command. The query would be as follows:

```
select * from mytable  where  WEEKDAY(CONVERT_TZ(datetime_field, source_timezone, target_timezone))=4;
/* example */
select * from mytable  where  WEEKDAY(CONVERT_TZ(datetime_field, "UTC", 'Australia/ACT'))=4;
```